# CMD: loop over folders and add as parameter

Tags: windows, cmd, arguments

I have server and mods in folder `D:\Mods` and I run server with cmd:

**server.bat**

```
"C:\server.exe" -mod=D:\Mods\@mod1;D:\Mods\@mod2;D:\Mods\@custom_mod3;
```

I have there various amount of mods in folder, so when I update them I need to write it to command line.

**How to automate this process and load all mods from folder?** Pattern is that mod have "@" before name, so I can use some loop to read all mods in folder and add them to command line.

Answer (score 0):

Use dir to list the mods, loop over them with FOR

```
    set modcom=
    for /F "tokens=*" %%G In ('dir /B @*') DO (
    call :setmod %%G
    )
    echo %modcom%
    "C:\server.exe" -mod=%modcom%
    goto :eof

    :setmod
    echo %1
    echo %modcom%
    set modcom=%1;%modcom%
    echo %modcom%
```

Comment: I am complete noob at bash, but I have understanding in basic programming languages. Echo means to show on screen, can you modify it for basic usage in *.bat file?

Comment: @Ing.MichalHudak, this is a Windows [tag:batch-file] but not [tag:bash]...

Comment: The echo statements are not necessary, they were added so that I could see that the final value of %modcom% was correct

Comment: How to define DIR which one to search in ? Lets say for example `D:\mods\`

Comment: Just add it to the dir statement, e.g. 'dir /B D:\mods\@*'

Comment: can it be loop like this ?  `for /d %%G in ("D:\Addons\*") do (`. I think its same result. Searching for `/d` directories

Comment: That looks like it should work, or you could add the /A:D switch to the dir command to list only folders